# mod rewrite to route based on a uri segment (wordpress permalink)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Wordpress Experts:

So, my wordpress instance is currently set to use friendly urls.  My current rewrite rules look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Which basically means: send everything to index.php for dispatching.

What I NEED to do, is whenever someone accesses my page /promo, I send the rest of the uri to that controller (which is a file promo.php attached to the page via Template Name: Promo) but it would still need to be piped through the index.php to do that.

In a nutshell, I want /promo/fakecompany to technically behave like this to wordpress:  index.php?page=promo&fakecompany

Or even a redirect that would take the second segment of anything beyond /promo and create a querystring out of it  i.e. a dynamic kind of this:

```
Redirect 301 /promo/fakecompany /promo/?fakecompany
Redirect 301 /promo/fakecompany/referpage /promo/?fakecompany&referpage
```

Is there a way to do this?  Or possibly a more elegant solution?  Worst comes to worse, I'm just going to have to hardcode in a redirect for the moment:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rules say : redirect anything that is not a regular file or a directory to index.php

For your request :

```
RewriteRule ^/promo/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=promo&$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/promo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /promo/?$1&$2
```

Should work (provided you place it before the current rules)